# Oracle View problem with Select and division by zero

Tags: sql, oracle, null, view

I want to create an view in Oracle which calculates an "utilization rate in percent".

```
AS SELECT
  sw.SWITCH_ID,
  sw.ASSET_ID,
  sw.SYSTEMNAME,
  sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS,
  sw.INSTALLED_PORTS,
  sw.USED_PORTS,
  (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100 AS UTIL_INSTALLED_PORTS,
  sw.RES_INFRASTRUCTURE_PORTS,
  sw.USED_INFRASTRUCTURE_PORTS,
  sw.FREE_INFRASTRUCTURE_PORTS,
  (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100 AS UTIL_INFRASTRUCTURE_PORTS,
  sw.RESERVED_DEVICE_PORTS,
  sw.USED_DEVICE_PORTS,
  sw.FREE_DEVICE_PORTS,
  (sw.FREE_DEVICE_PORTS/sw.RESERVED_DEVICE_PORTS)*100 AS UTIL_DEVICE_PORTS,
  sw.RUN_DATE
```

Problem: sometimes sw.INSTALLED_PORTS or sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS can be NULL (same for other UTIL Rows).

Is there any nice way to do something like:

```
if (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS or sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS == null) 
      UTIL_INSTALLABLE_PORTS = null 
else (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100 AS UTIL_INSTALLABLE_PORTS,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divizion by NULL is not the same as divizion by zero (as you reference the problem in the title).

`select 1/null from dual` = null
`select null/null from dual` = null

So you'll automatically get what you want by `(sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100`.

I think, the problem is when `sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS` is zero. In this case you can use the following:

```
case
  when sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS = 0 then null
  else (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100
end
```

Answer (score 5):

or a little shorter:

```
sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/NULLIF(sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS,0)
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 4):

```
CASE
   WHEN sw.INSTALLED_PORTS IS NULL OR sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS IS NULL THEN NULL
   ELSE (sw.INSTALLED_PORTS/sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS)*100
END UTIL_INFRASTRUCTURE_PORTS
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use COALESCE() which returns the first non-null from its arguments, like :

```
(COALESCE(sw.INSTALLED_PORTS, 0)/COALESCE(sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS,1))*100  
 AS UTIL_DEVICE_PORTS
```

Note that I used 1 as the coalesce default in the denominator, you don't want a DIVIDE/0 instead.

Comment: I don't think that's the same thing. He wants the UTIL_INSTALLABLE_PORTS to be null if either sw.INSTALLED_PORTS or sw.MAX_INSTALLABLE_PORTS is null. Your code will return 0 for the following case, but according to OP's code the result should be NULL:  
SELECT (COALESCE(NULL, 0)/COALESCE(NULL,1))*100  
 AS UTIL_DEVICE_PORTS FROM dual